# Ruby Eventmachine queueing problem

Tags: ruby, queue, eventmachine

I have a Http client written in Ruby that can make synchronous requests to URLs. However, to quickly execute multiple requests I decided to use Eventmachine. The idea is to
queue all the requests and execute them using eventmachine.

```
class EventMachineBackend
  ...
  ...
  def execute(request)
    $q ||= EM.Queue.new
    $q.push(request)
    $q.pop {|request| request.invoke}
    EM.run{EM.next_tick {EM.stop}}
  end
  ...
end
```

Forgive my use of a global queue variable. I will refactor it later. Is what I am doing in `EventMachineBackend#execute` the right way of using Eventmachine queues?

One problem I see in my implementation is it is essentially synchronous. I push a request, pop and execute the request and wait for it to complete.

Could anyone suggest a better implementation.

Answer (score 10):

Your the request logic has to be asynchronous for it to work with EventMachine, I suggest that you use [em-http-request](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request). You can find [an example on how to use it here](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/blob/master/examples/fetch.rb), it shows how to run the requests in parallel. An even better interface for running multiple connections in parallel is the [MultiRequest class](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/blob/master/lib/em-http/multi.rb) from the same gem.

If you want to queue requests and only run a fixed number of them in parallel you can do something like this:

```
EM.run do
  urls = [...] # regular array with URLs
  active_requests = 0

  # this routine will be used as callback and will
  # be run when each request finishes
  when_done = proc do
    active_requests -= 1
    if urls.empty? && active_requests == 0
      # if there are no more urls, and there are no active
      # requests it means we're done, so shut down the reactor
      EM.stop
    elsif !urls.empty?
      # if there are more urls launch a new request
      launch_next.call
    end
  end

  # this routine launches a request
  launch_next = proc do
    # get the next url to fetch
    url = urls.pop
    # launch the request, and register the callback
    request = EM::HttpRequest.new(url).get
    request.callback(&when_done)
    request.errback(&when_done)
    # increment the number of active requests, this
    # is important since it will tell us when all requests
    # are done
    active_requests += 1
  end

  # launch three requests in parallel, each will launch
  # a new requests when done, so there will always be 
  # three requests active at any one time, unless there
  # are no more urls to fetch
  3.times do
    launch_next.call
  end
end
```

Caveat emptor, there may very well be some detail I've missed in the code above.

If you think it's hard to follow the logic in my example, welcome to the world of evented programming. It's really tricky to write readable evented code. It all goes backwards. Sometimes it helps to start reading from the end.

I've assumed that you don't want to add more requests after you've started downloading, it doesn't look like it from the code in your question, but should you want to you can rewrite my code to use an `EM::Queue` instead of a regular array, and remove the part that does `EM.stop`, since you will not be stopping. You can probably remove the code that keeps track of the number of active requests too, since that's not relevant. The important part would look something like this:

```
launch_next = proc do
  urls.pop do |url|
    request = EM::HttpRequest.new(url).get
    request.callback(&launch_next)
    request.errback(&launch_next)
  end
end
```

Also, bear in mind that my code doesn't actually do anything with the response. The response will be passed as an argument to the `when_done` routine (in the first example). I also do the same thing for success and error, which you may not want to do in a real application.

Comment: Great solution, the only thing is that the when_done proc is not known to the launch_next proc, so you will need to write those out. At least that is what worked for me.

Comment: Does this lead to a stack level too deep error? I have a similarly  recursive solution that is good for scraping around 1600 pages before I get stack level too deep. Does your solution exclude this by using procs?

Comment: This method should not result in a stack overflow since it's not strictly recursive (the functions don't call themselves, they schedule themselves to be called by the reactor at a later time).